# Simplifying $\sum_{k=0}^n{\cos((3k+1)x)}$ using De Moivre's formula.

Tags: complex-analysis

My guess would be to define $z=\cos x$ and then we'd have the series

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{z^{(3k+1)}} = z + z^4 + z^7 + \dots + z^{3n+1}$$

But, given it's not a geometric series, I'm not sure of how I'd go about calculating the sum.

Thanks!

Comment: you are on the right track but with $z=e^{i(3k+1)x}$ and then your sum is the real part, while the sum in $z$ is indeed a geometric series once you factor $z$

Comment: Wouldn't $e^{i(3k+1)x}$ be generally not a real number? Also, I might be being a little thick, but, how would one go about factoring $z$ to make that sum a geometric series? Thanks! @Conrad

Comment: For get the first question, @Conrad, $z$ would be the real part of $e^{i(3k+1)x}$, obvisouly.

Comment: Mathematica code `Sum[Cos[(3 k + 1) x], {k, 0, n}] // Simplify // TeXForm` yields
$ \csc\left(\frac{3 x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3}{2} (n+1) x\right)\
\cos\left(\frac{3 n x}{2}+x\right) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z:=z^3$.

Your expression can be written as the real part of

$$z(1+Z+Z^2+ \cdots + Z^n)$$ where we recognize a geometric series that can be written as the real part of

$$z(1-Z^{n+1})\dfrac{1}{1-Z}=zZ^{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}(Z^{-\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-Z^{\tfrac{n+1}{2}})\dfrac{1}{Z^{1/2}(Z^{-1/2}-Z^{1/2})}$$

i.e., the real part of:

$$zZ^{\tfrac{n}{2}}\underbrace{(\tfrac{Z^{-\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-Z^{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}}{2i})}_{-\sin\left(\tfrac{3}{2}(n+1)x\right)}\dfrac{1}{\tfrac{(Z^{-1/2}-Z^{1/2})}{2i}}$$

giving the expression

$$\cos\left((\tfrac{3}{2}n+1) x\right)\sin\left(\tfrac{3}{2}(n+1)x\right)\csc\left(\tfrac{3}{2}x\right)$$

which agrees with the one found by Somos.